# Stack Overflow - Buffer Location in Memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, security, debugging

I'm researching buffer overflows (on IA32 architecture) and I would like to clarify one particular thing with this example program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char array[512];
  if(argc > 1)
    strcpy(array, argv[1]);
}
```

I followed the ebp,esp register change during execution of the assembly code:
Dump of assembler code for function main:

```
   0x080483c4 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x080483c5 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483c7 <+3>:     sub    esp,0x208
   0x080483cd <+9>:     cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x1
   0x080483d1 <+13>:    jle    0x80483ed <main+41>
   0x080483d3 <+15>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x080483d6 <+18>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x080483d9 <+21>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x080483db <+23>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x080483df <+27>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x200]
   0x080483e5 <+33>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080483e8 <+36>:    call   0x80482f4 <strcpy@plt>
   0x080483ed <+41>:    leave
   0x080483ee <+42>:    ret
```

The esp,ebp register values were:

```
program start
  esp: 0xbffff24c
  ebp: 0xbffff2c8

push ebp
  esp: 0xbffff248
  ebp: 0xbffff2c8

mov ebp,esp
  esp: 0xbffff248
  ebp: 0xbffff248

sub esp,0x208
  esp: 0xbffff040
  ebp: 0xbffff248

strcpy call (ebp is overwritten)
  esp: 0xbffff250
  ebp: 0x41414141
```

when I inputed 520 characters 'a', which resulted in EBP, EIP being overflown. And the memory looks like this:

```
Lower Memory Addresses
0xbffff070:     0xbffff078      0xbffff492      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
0xbffff080:     0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
0xbffff090:     0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
0xbffff0a0:     0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
0xbffff0b0:     0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
...
0xbffff270:     0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa      0xaaaaaaaa
Higher Memory Addresses
```

The thing that interests me is: Why do buffer start at address 0xbffff078, if the ESP points at address 0xbffff040 (when the place for local variable - buffer - is reserved on the stack). The buffer should have been saved at 0xbffff040 address. Can anybody explain why it is not?

Comment: How did your `'a'` characters get turned into `0xaaaaaaaa`?  Are you showing us the whole program?

Comment: Are you sure the address of `array` was 0xbffff078, not 0xbffff048? Maybe the postlude of `strcpy` attempted to do some stack things which overwrote the 8 bytes at 0xbffff070?

Comment: Is the memory dump from the same invocation of the program as the register trace?

Comment: Hi, I think I solved it: aaz your answer helped me. Of course what am I thinking, the answer was so obvious. The outputs are not from the same invocation of the program: one is from the gdb run, and the other is directly from bash, so of course it wasn't the same, since gdb uses more space on the stack, so it's addresses for local variables were lower on from the bash invocation. I would mark as: problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler decided to allocate space for both the local variable *and* the parameters passed to `strcpy()` on the stack at the same time.

```
sub    esp,0x208                # 0x200 for array, 8 for 2 pointers
...
mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax  # argv[1], not push
mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax      # array
```

So the array is actually at `esp+8` (or `ebp-0x200`, as the compiler refers to it).

**Edit:**
`esp` is different between invocations of the program, especially depending on the number of arguments. `0xbffff040` or `0xbffff070`.

The buffer is at `0xbffff048`, not `0xbffff040`. Or at `0xbffff078`, not `0xbffff070`. Ask the debugger where it is to check.

In the memory dump the buffer has `0xaa` (I guess this is uninitialized memory before the call). In front of this you can see the two pointers that are passed to `strcpy()`.

Comment: Yes I make a mistake, it's 0xbffff048, but that still doesn't explain why it's at 0xbffff078 and not at 0xbffff048, where it should have been (because free space on stack was reserved for it).

Comment: I guessed that before doing the memory dump you restarted the program without arguments. So the stack frame is higher up and the buffer is filled with `0xaa` instead of `0x41` ("a"). Is this the case?